# retain column sequence by row with tidyr::gather in r

Tags: r, tidyr

When using gather, I would like to retain the column sequence by row, where gather appears to retain column sequence by column.

```
library("magrittr")

stocks <- tibble::tibble(
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)

stocks
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    time                X      Y      Z
#>    <date>          <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 2009-01-01  0.0000553 -0.348 -2.39 
#>  2 2009-01-02  1.82      -0.306  0.141
#>  3 2009-01-03  1.11       1.86  -3.12 
#>  4 2009-01-04  0.424      2.05   3.73 
#>  5 2009-01-05  0.255      0.527 -0.605
#>  6 2009-01-06 -2.54      -1.69  -1.97 
#>  7 2009-01-07  0.0217     0.722  0.537
#>  8 2009-01-08  0.715      3.26   7.38 
#>  9 2009-01-09 -1.95       3.08   5.46 
#> 10 2009-01-10 -0.219     -1.53  -2.04

gather_ex1 <- stocks %>% 
  tidyr::gather(stock, price, -time)

gather_ex1
#> # A tibble: 30 x 3
#>    time       stock      price
#>    <date>     <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 2009-01-01 X      0.0000553
#>  2 2009-01-02 X      1.82     
#>  3 2009-01-03 X      1.11     
#>  4 2009-01-04 X      0.424    
#>  5 2009-01-05 X      0.255    
#>  6 2009-01-06 X     -2.54     
#>  7 2009-01-07 X      0.0217   
#>  8 2009-01-08 X      0.715    
#>  9 2009-01-09 X     -1.95     
#> 10 2009-01-10 X     -0.219    
#> # ... with 20 more rows

gather_ex2 <- stocks %>% 
  tidyr::gather(stock, price, -time, factor_key = FALSE)

gather_ex2
#> # A tibble: 30 x 3
#>    time       stock      price
#>    <date>     <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 2009-01-01 X      0.0000553
#>  2 2009-01-02 X      1.82     
#>  3 2009-01-03 X      1.11     
#>  4 2009-01-04 X      0.424    
#>  5 2009-01-05 X      0.255    
#>  6 2009-01-06 X     -2.54     
#>  7 2009-01-07 X      0.0217   
#>  8 2009-01-08 X      0.715    
#>  9 2009-01-09 X     -1.95     
#> 10 2009-01-10 X     -0.219    
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

The first row sequence in stocks is 0.000553, -0.348, -2.39, but I don't seem to have an option to gather in this sequence, instead I receive rows for all of column X, then rows for column Y, etc.

So, the preferred output would be to gather each row in column sequence:

```
gather_preferred_output
#> # A tibble: 30 x 3
#>    time       stock      price
#>    <date>     <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 2009-01-01 X      0.0000553
#>  2 2009-01-01 Y      -0.348     
#>  3 2009-01-01 Z      -2.39     
#>  4 2009-01-02 X      1.82
```

...

Comment: Please try `stocks %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -c(time, rowid)) %>%
 arrange(rowid, var)`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you.